# Added new row to datagrid but the value keeps on the first row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I tried making simple program that add new row in my datagridview when I click a button and send a specific value to new added row. Here's the code

http://pastebin.com/mN5QwL1Z

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Button2.Click
    Dim baris As Integer
    baris = 0
    perintah.Connection = koneksi
    perintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    perintah.CommandText = "select * from film where kode_film ='" & TextBox11.Text & "'"

    dr = perintah.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        dr.Read()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(0).Value = dr("kode_film")
        DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(1).Value = dr("nama_film")
        DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(2).Value = dr("stok")
        dr.Close()

    End If

    dr.Close()



End Sub
```

The problem is, each time I click the button, it do makes a new row in datagridview, but the value keeps on the first row and not inserted in the new added value.

Have googled so many times but haven't found the answer. Need your hand, guys.
Sorry my bad English.

Comment: you have to increment baris

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the value of `baris` anywhere so you always get the row at index 0.  The `Add` method returns the index of the new row so use that.  Better still, use the overload of `Add` that takes the cell values as arguments, so you create and populate the row in a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Button2.Click
Dim baris As Integer
baris = 0
perintah.Connection = koneksi
perintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
perintah.CommandText = "select * from film where kode_film ='" & TextBox11.Text & "'"

dr = perintah.ExecuteReader()
If dr.HasRows = True Then
    dr.Read()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(0).Value = dr("kode_film")
    DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(1).Value = dr("nama_film")
    DataGridView1.Rows(baris).Cells(2).Value = dr("stok")
    dr.Close()
    baris = baris + 1

End If

dr.Close()



End Sub
```

Had changed the value of baris but the value still on the first row and it replaces the previous value I inserted.